# Calculating different data with PHP

Tags: php

First of all sorry for the confusing title but i didn't know how to call it.

I'm doing a function in PHP that calculates all the numbers between 0 and 999999 and is stored in an Array. But when i echo the Array i don't get all the values. Is there any top of calculations in PHP?

Here goes the code:

```
function Number() {
    $totalNumbers = array();
    $number = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
        $totalNumbers[] = $number++;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
        echo $totalNumbers[$i] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

And here an image from the last result in the web:

https://gyazo.com/b634a828b1f7064bd0a0a11609b5426b

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably just overloading your web browser. Ten million characters all in one line with no whitespace is quite a lot to handle. Try changing `"<br>"` to `"<br>\n"` and see if that helps at all.

Comment: Alternatively, the problem might be that the PHP script is timing out. If it doesn't manage to push all the data to your browser within [`max_execution_time`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) seconds, then the script will just stop running.

Comment: For what i see the error was from the lanes created. Thanks!

Comment: `$range  = range(0,999999); var_dump($range);`